# Force WCF to accept different SOAP message

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I'm not sure the title really gets across what I need to do. I want to force or coerce or whatever a WCF service to accept a slightly different SOAP message. Here is what the service expects:

```
<sch:modifyCandidateNotification>
<!--Optional:-->
     <sch:request vueCandidateID="?" clientCandidateID="?" clientCode="?">
```

...

but here is what I want to send to the service:

```
<sch:modifyCandidateNotification vueCandidateID="?" clientCandidateID="?" clientCode="?">
```

I'm not responsible for sending the SOAP, one of our partners is and they can't alter what they are sending. I don't want the  structure at all.

I've tried adding [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)] to the interface, but to no avail. Also, I'm using a basicHttpBinding. I've tried with the wsHttpBinding and did not see any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not showing enough of your soap message and service contract / data contracts so it is hard to say what exactly are you looking for but my guess is that `MessageContract` should help you.